# Mturks: how to run hits in a loop

Tags: loops, mechanicalturk

I have generated a survey template in Mturks. I want to enable workers to run hits in a loop, such that their answer to the previous hit will be used as input to the next hit.
For example:

- Hit 1: watch a RANDOM movie, then: which movie would you like to watch next?
- Hit 2 (same worker): watch the SELECTED movie from hit 1, then: which movie would you like to watch next?
- ... continue if desired

Is that possible?

Comment: @Mani: Please do not propose edits where you add some seemingly random markups. Please don't use bold text for keywords and please don't format some non-code text as code. Also, please remove any noise like "thanks" from posts when suggesting edits.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible natively in MTurk. Each HIT is independent and displayed in a pseudo-random order. What you're describing is probably best set up as a custom, server-side application that you host elsewhere (not on MTurk) and point workers to via a link or using an `ExternalQuestion`-type HIT that you create via the API.